# Average percent value in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sum, average

I'm trying to divide a value of the count by the value of a subquery and multiplying by 100 to obtain its percent. That code below works...

```
SELECT data, rota as rt, COUNT(cliente_id) / 
(
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cliente_id)
 FROM vw_grafico
 WHERE rota = rt  
) * 100 ) AS porcentagem

FROM vw_grafico
WHERE WEEKDAY(data)+1  = rota 
AND YEAR(data) = 2013
GROUP BY month(data)
ORDER BY data ASC
```

...but, add to that, I need the average of this value by month, and that's my problem... I have the error "Invalid use of group function" when I try to do this:

```
SELECT data, rota as rt, AVG(COUNT(cliente_id) / 
(
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cliente_id)
 FROM vw_grafico
 WHERE rota = rt  
) * 100 ) AS porcentagem

FROM vw_grafico
WHERE WEEKDAY(data)+1 = rota 
AND YEAR(data) = 2013
GROUP BY month(data)
ORDER BY data ASC
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select list fields( not aggregates) must be Subset of Group by List that in your query this is not true and your error is for that.
```

in your query :

```
SELECT data, rota as rt, AVG(COUNT(cliente_id) / 
(
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cliente_id)
 FROM vw_grafico
 WHERE rota = rt  
) * 100 ) AS porcentagem

FROM vw_grafico
WHERE WEEKDAY(data)+1 = rota 
AND YEAR(data) = 2013
GROUP BY month(data)
ORDER BY data ASC
```

Select list is :

```
data, rota as rt
```

and 
Group List is :

```
month(data)
```

that  select list fields is not  subset of Group list. all select list fields must be in group list for examplme  :

```
SELECT month(data), rota as rt, AVG(COUNT(cliente_id) / 
(
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cliente_id)
 FROM vw_grafico
 WHERE rota = rt  
) * 100 ) AS porcentagem

FROM vw_grafico
WHERE WEEKDAY(data)+1 = rota 
AND YEAR(data) = 2013
GROUP BY month(data), rota
ORDER BY data ASC
```

Comment: i didn't get what you said

Comment: my means just syntax laws and not exat query

Comment: i thought about that, haha, but i haven't succeed yet